# I Have three columns(say P1,P2,P3) in a table. how to compare(P2<P3<P1) if is true return '1' else '0'.. how can i write SQL query for this scenario

Tags: sql

I Have three columns(say P1,P2,P3) in a table. how to compare(P2<P3<P1) if is true return '1' else '0'.. how can i write SQL query for this scenario

Comment: Simply use a `case` _expression_. `case when p2 < p3 and p3 < p1 then ...`

Comment: In standard SQL you can simply use: `select  p2 < p3 and p3 < p1 from ...` which will return `true` or `false`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mysql, you can try the IF function.

```
select IF(P1 > P3 and P3> P2, '1', '0') as r from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need use `CASE ... END`.

```sql
SELECT
    P1,
    P2,
    P3,
    CASE
        WHEN P2 < P3 AND P3 < P1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS Result
FROM Table;
```

For each row, SQL will evaluate the condition in the `WHEN` clause and use the result programmed in the `THEN` clause. You can have many `WHEN` conditions if you need something more complex. If none of the `WHEN` clauses is true, it will display the value for `ELSE`.

In the example above, I just added `P1, P2, P3` so you can better see how it just work as another column in the query, but they are not required for `CASE` to work.

More examples:

- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp